# Pulling data from two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

Slots:

```
id      Callsign    Received    CTOT    DLY     InsertDate  
1670    AFR115G     021410      1620    OA 83   2019-07-03 06:55:29
1671    AFR115G     021415      1624    OA 83   2019-07-03 07:05:29
1672    AFR115G     021425      1628    OA 83   2019-07-03 07:15:29
1673    AFR115G     021435      1604    OA 83   2019-07-03 07:25:29
```

Callsigns:

```
id      Airline     FltNo   Callsign    Dest    
00001   TOM         1118    TOM1DX      CFU
00002   AFR         1159    AFR115G     CDG
```

I'm trying to get the last slot received from the `Slots` table for each unique callsign received on a given day, then using the callsign get the flight info from the `callsigns` table.

I thought I had it working until this morning when certain slots were not being retrieved.

My current query:

```sql
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(Callsigns.Airline), 
  Callsigns.FltNo, 
  Callsigns.Dest, 
  Slots.Callsign, 
  Slots.Received, 
  Slots.CTOT, 
  Slots.DLY 
FROM 
  Slots 
  INNER JOIN(
    SELECT 
      Callsign, 
      MAX(Received) AS LastRcvd, 
      CTOT 
    FROM 
      Slots 
    GROUP BY 
      Callsign
  ) LatestSlot ON Slots.Callsign = LatestSlot.Callsign 
  AND Slots.Received = LatestSlot.LastRcvd 
  AND Slots.Received LIKE = ? 
  INNER JOIN Callsigns ON Callsigns.Callsign = LatestSlot.Callsign 
ORDER BY 
  Airline ASC
```

Im not well versed in the use of joins etc any help would be greatly appreciated.

Expected Output:

```
Airline FltNo   Dest    Callsign    Received    CTOT    DLY
AF      1159    CDG     AFR115G     021435      1604    OA 83
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? What result do you get and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: what's your question ? .. you have an error ?  show the exact error message,, wrong result?  .. show your expected  result

Comment: with my current query some results seem to get omitted, it should return a slot for each flight where the "Recieved" column starts with the given day of the month.
So the correct query should produce:
The newest slot recieved and the relevant flight into from the Callsigns table for every Callsign that is in the Slots Table where the Recieved value starts with the current day of the month.

The Receieved value is formatted as such: "ddhhmm"

Comment: @scaisEdge added expected output to original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT 
  c.Airline, 
  c.FltNo, 
  c.Dest, 
  s.Callsign, 
  s.Received, 
  s.CTOT, 
  s.DLY 
FROM 
  Slots s
JOIN Callsigns c ON c.Callsign = s.Callsign
 AND InsertDate=( SELECT max(InsertDate) 
                    FROM Slots
                   WHERE date(InsertDate)='2019-07-03')
```